# JS Native NextEventLoop

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecma

Given that async programming has been commonplace in Javascript since long ago, the number of calls to window.setTimeout seem, to me, to be very hack-ish. I understand how the VM works and how the event loop works. The point being, does anyone know the reasoning for why the ecma authors aren't choosing to add some sort of "nextEventLoop" or "defer" call that will force a block of logic to execute later?

I cringe every time I see setTimeout(0) because no author has ever intended to set a timeout of zero, ever. So why continue forcing this hack upon us?

Or, are there better alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

As of ES6, `Promise.resolve().then(() => { ... })` does what you're asking pretty much, and there are Promise polyfills available for most environments that are still just ES5. Most of the polyfills even avoid `setTimeout` in favor of better faster options where possible.

Comment: Yeah but, this is exactly what I'm talking about. This to me is no different than setTimeout and much more verbose. Effectively this uses a facility of the language that is not explicitly for deferring action, it uses a _side effect_ of an async semantic to achieve the goal of "hey JS, defer this action to after the current queue". Does that make sense? I do appreciate your answer but it's just another way to skin a cat, so to speak.

Comment: I guess it depends on your viewpoint. `setTimeout` isn't even part of the ES spec, it's part of HTML, and copied into Node. `Promise` is the only user-visible, ES-specced way to queue things in later turns of the event loop.